# Group By with Django's queryset

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a model in Django and this is how it looks like with fewer fields -

[image]

I want to group the rows w.r.t `buy_price_per_unit` and at the same time I also want to know the total units on sale for that `buy_price_per_unit`.

So in our case only two distinct `buy_price_per_unit` are available `(9, 10)`. Hence the query would return only two rows like this -

[image]

The one last condition which I have to meet is the query result should be in descending order of `buy_price_per_unit`.

This is what I have tried so far -

```
orders = Orders.objects.values('id', 'buy_price_per_unit')\
        .annotate(units=Sum("units"))\
        .order_by("-buy_price_per_unit")\
```

The response for the query above was -

```
[
  {
    "id": 13,
    "buy_price_per_unit": 10,
    "units": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "buy_price_per_unit": 9,
    "units": 10
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "buy_price_per_unit": 9,
    "units": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "buy_price_per_unit": 9,
    "units": 1
  }
]
```

The problem with this response is that even for the same price multiple records are being returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you have `id` in `.values` and based on the underlying query, it is grouping on `id` and `buy_price_per_unit` both.

So simply remove `id` from `.values`

```py
orders = Orders.objects.values('buy_price_per_unit')\
        .annotate(units=Sum("units"))\
        .order_by("-buy_price_per_unit")\
```